# Changing Themes Dynamically to a website in ASP.Net MVC website?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

How to change themes of website upon change of drop down or a checkbox is checked, using Jquery? Is there a plug in?

Comment: I assume you mean you want to switch (or add) a stylesheet?

Comment: Yes exactly.. based on some conditions, i want to apply skins.

Comment: "Apply skins" does not mean what I asked.  Do you want to totally replace an existing stylesheet, or do you want to append a new one, leaving the existing ones in place.  You need to give us more information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to change your style sheets which change your themes here is a snippet for that :

you may use a dynamic method like this for the style sheets :

```
function updateStyleSheet(filename) {

    newstylesheet = "Content/css/" + filename + ".css";
    if ($("#dynamic_css").length == 0) {
        $("head").append("<link>")
        css = $("head").children(":last");
        css.attr({
            id: "dynamic_css",
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            href: newstylesheet
        });
    } else {
        $("#dynamic_css").attr("href", newstylesheet);
    }

}
```

Comment: they put jquery tag in the question , i wouldn't worry about a pure javascript solution

Comment: yes i agree with you i only wants to give him more options and i gave him both  and he is free to choose :) thank you

Comment: I would delete the top 2 solutions in this answer the third is by far the best, its so much better, it's not worth even offering the other 2 , i'm going to delete my answer too and just upvote yours,  I wouldn't want someone that doesn't know too much about javascript to choose mine , or your top answer not knowing how much better the other one is

Comment: ok , and thanks your comment is appreciated :) i will remove the first two answers .

Comment: Is that how the OP is changing themes?  Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Archer - all of these solutions assume this is how themes are changed.  With the information provided from OP this is really the most likely scenario, they are going to have to make additional comments if this is not the case

Comment: Which is why I asked the question before rushing into an answer.  You're probably right, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code for changing the Theme/Style of your webpage.

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">

 //Handle this below code however you want
$("#stylesheet").attr({href : 'your css URL here'});
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/qp49wj3d/2/)

Hope it helps you.. :)